# How to show post categories in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

i'm making a theme in WP but i can't find a way to show the categories of a single post, i want to display the categories that have a single post not all categories, i was using...

```
<?php $args = array ('hide_empty' => 0,'title_li' => false,'style' => 'none',);wp_list_categories($args);?>
```

But this is showing all categories and i don't need this. I'm new in this and i'm gonna be happy if somebody can help me :D

Before i forget, sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all categories for particular post using below code

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id,'category');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo $cat_name = $term->name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $cat_id = $term->term_id;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use it but don't show anything

Comment: I found how do it, is <?php the_category(',');?> so simple, is the disadvantage of being new XD. Anyway thanks for answer my question

Answer (score 0):

If somebody need it, is `<?php the_category(',');?>`

Comment: So... did you "accept"" an answer that didn't work?