# Show all categories of a single WordPress article?

Tags: php, wordpress

In a WordPress theme I use, above the headline also the category is displayed, to which the article belongs incl. a link to the category page. But some articles are assigned to more than one category.

```
 <a class="cat-link" href="<?php $category = get_the_category(); $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category[1]->cat_name ); $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id ); echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>"><span class="post-cat left"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo esc_html( $category[1]->cat_name ); ?></span></a>
```

I can now query the content of the array [x] individually but I do not know beforehand how many categories I need to display.

Do you have an idea of how I can read all categories of an article and display them in the article itself including the link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show post categories in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819634/how-to-show-post-categories-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should try:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me all the categories available on my page. But I only need the X categories, in which the WordPress post is located

Comment: I corrected my answer, it should be `get_the_category()` like in your code instead of `get_categories()`

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's sufficient to use this (inside the loop):

```
<?php the_category(', ') ?>
```

This will list all categories of the current post (each linked to the according category page), separated by the character that's inside the single quotes in the brackets, i.e. a comma followed by a space in the example above.

Note: You won't need to put a link (`<a ...>...</a>`)  around it as you did in your code - this code/function already contains the links.